# How is the scope of pattern variables resolved in java?

Tags: java, pattern-matching, jls, java-14

I was going through the pattern variables in java. While reading the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) it mentioned several conditions regarding when a pattern variable is introduced.
It mentions -

> The analysis relies on the technical term "introduced by", which has the following form:
>
> - a pattern variable is *introduced by* an expression *when true*
> - a pattern variable is *introduced by* an expression *when false*
> - a pattern variable is *introduced by* a statement

In 6.3.1 it mentions Scope for Pattern Variables in Expressions under which it states when pattern variables are introduced for `&&`, `||`, `!`, `?:`, etc.

But I feel the explanation is very confusing, can anyone elaborate on `&&`, `||`, `!`

Example of pattern variables-

```
Object o = "a";

if(o instanceof String s) {
    System.out.println(s); 
}
```

**Where I am confused-**

```
class foo {
    String s, n, p, m;

    void method() {
        Object o = "s";
        if (!(o instanceof Integer s) && o instanceof Integer n) {
            System.out.println(s + " " + n);  // n in scope but s is not in scope
        } else {
            System.out.println(s + " " + n); // neither s nor n is in scope
        }
        System.out.println(s + " " + n); // neither s nor n is in scope (Instance variables s and n over here)

        if (!(o instanceof String p) || o instanceof Integer m) {
            System.out.println(p + " " + m); // neither p nor m is in scope (Instance variables p and m over here)
        } else {
            System.out.println(p + " " + m); // p in scope but m is not in scope
        }

    }

}
```

I don't get how it resolute the scope of a variable at compile time. Also, why isn't `s` in the scope of else block and why is `p` in the scope of else block. I don't understand how pattern variable scoping works with a mix of `&&`,`||` and `!`.

Please give simple as well as complicated examples.
Please try to explain it with simple and difficult examples, would really be helpful.

Comment: I was in the middle of editing, it was showing differently in preview and different when I posted it. Thanks..

Comment: Maybe it's me.. but I can't really easily guess what this question is about. What *pattern*s are you referring to? maybe giving a clearer description, with a possibility of some code snippet, would make the question more explicit?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Patterns are defined in the JLS - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.30

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I added an example.

Comment: @kaya3 ah, so.. it's the pattern that we use in pattern matching.. makes better sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it's now clear what patterns are we talking about. Now, what is exactly confusing for you @BeastMaster64?

Comment: The whole explanation, it's way too confusing, I am editing the question to make some more sense.

Comment: @BeastMaster64 can [this](https://medium.com/javarevisited/java-14-new-language-features-1e185b7f120) be of any help to you? I have a in-details examination of pattern matching and its variable scope.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri It's good but I am looking for something more detailed with some complicated examples including `&&`, `||`,etc.

Comment: @BeastMaster64 with all respect, but I still don't understand what exactly is confusing for you.. what is the problem with `&&` or `||`.. that's why I suggested to be clear and explicit (with some unclear to you code snippet.. and not just snippet of how pattern matching looks like) about your problem. I think, question might have been formulated in a clearer fashion.

Comment: “resolute” is not a verb, so “I don't get how it resolute…” makes no sense. Please fix it. Perhaps, you mean “resolve”, but it’s not clear what “it” refers to.

Comment: +1 to this question from me. I also find Java spec on this to be overly confusing. For example, I have hard time understanding 6.3.1.1. "Conditional-And Operator &&" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets just consider this:

```
if (!(o instanceof Integer s)) {
    System.out.println(s);
```

It says:

> When `o` is an `Integer` bind it to `s`.
>
> Then if `o` is not an `Integer`, print `s`.

Intuitively: when `o` is not an `Integer`, we **didn't** bind it to `s`, so `s` is meaningless.

If you look at a more complicated example, it will most likely have this kind of logic at its root.

The section of the JLS that specifies this is ... complicated.  But I don't think you need to understand all of that complexity to use pattern variables.  Just use the intuitive meaning behind these two sentences from the [JLS 6.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> *"The scope of a pattern variable declaration (that is, a local variable declared by a pattern) is the part of the program that **might be executed** after the matching of a value against the pattern **has succeeded**. It is determined by considering the program points where the pattern variable is **definitely** matched in a region beginning with the pattern that declares the pattern variable."*

So in our simple example, the `System.out.println(s)` is NOT part of the program that would be executed if `(o instanceof Integer s)` succeeded.  The `!` means that the *then* branch of this `if` is executed when `(o instanceof Integer s)` does not succeed.